# Last unit does not have enough valid bits with java 8 Base64

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I have next class for encryption and decryption:

```
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class EncryptorBean {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EncryptorBean.class);

    @Value("${security.encryptor.encryption-key}")
    private String encryptorEncryptionKey;

    @Value("${security.encryptor.salt}")
    private String encryptorSalt;

    @Value("${security.encryptor.password}")
    private String encryptorPassword;

    private static final int KEY_LENGTH = 256;
    private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static final int ITERATION_COUNT = 65536;
    private static final String PBE_ALGORITHM = "PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128";
    private static final String CIPHER_INSTANCE = "AES_256/GCM/NOPADDING";
    private static final int GCM_AUTHENTICATION_TAG_SIZE = 16;

    // the key
    private transient SecretKey key;
    Cipher cipher;

    /**
     * Post construct to creates secret key. In production we may want to avoid keeping the secret key hanging around in memory for very long.
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        try {
            // create the PBE key
            KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(encryptorPassword.toCharArray(), encryptorSalt.getBytes(), ITERATION_COUNT, KEY_LENGTH);
            SecretKey skey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(PBE_ALGORITHM).generateSecret(spec);
            // recast key as straightforward AES without padding.
            key = new SecretKeySpec(skey.getEncoded(), ALGORITHM);
        } catch (SecurityException | InvalidKeySpecException | NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            // handle appropriately...
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Encrypt String
     */
    public String encrypt(String plainText) {
        return encrypt(plainText, encryptorEncryptionKey);
    }

    public String encrypt(String plainText, String encryptionKey) {
        String cipherText = null;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_INSTANCE); // we must use it here to avoid java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Cannot reuse iv for GCM encryption
            GCMParameterSpec params = new GCMParameterSpec(GCM_AUTHENTICATION_TAG_SIZE * Byte.SIZE, encryptionKey.getBytes(), 0, 12);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, params);

            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            cipherText = Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(encrypted);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn(e.getMessage());
        }
        return cipherText;
    }

    /**
     * Decrypt String
     */
    public String decrypt(String cipherText) {
        return decrypt(cipherText, encryptorEncryptionKey);

    }

    public String decrypt(String cipherText, String encryptionKey) {
        String plainText = null;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_INSTANCE); // we must use it here to avoid java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Cannot reuse iv for GCM encryption
            GCMParameterSpec params = new GCMParameterSpec(GCM_AUTHENTICATION_TAG_SIZE * Byte.SIZE, encryptionKey.getBytes(), 0, 12);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, params);

            byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText);
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(bytes);
            plainText = new String(decrypted, "UTF8");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn(e.getMessage());
        }
        return plainText;
    }

    public boolean isEncoded(String cipherText) {
        boolean encoded = false;
        if (cipherText != null && !cipherText.trim().isEmpty()) {
            try {
                GCMParameterSpec params = new GCMParameterSpec(GCM_AUTHENTICATION_TAG_SIZE * Byte.SIZE, encryptorEncryptionKey.getBytes(), 0, 12);
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, params);
                byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText);
                cipher.doFinal(bytes);
                encoded = true;
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                // handle exception. Perhaps set value to null?
                // e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return encoded;
    }

}
```

But when i use it i always get a warning messages:

> **Illegal base64 character 40**
>
> and
>
> **Last unit does not have enough valid bits**

And actually in other environment i got this:

```
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Last unit does not have enough valid bits
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 2e
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 2e
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 2e
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 2e
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 40
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 2e
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 40
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 40
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 40
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 40
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 40
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 5f
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 40
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 40
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 2e
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 40
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 2e
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 40
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 2e
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 40
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 2e
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 2e
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 40
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 40
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 40
WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] xxx.xxx.xxx.EncryptorBean  : Illegal base64 character 24
```

So why i got this warning? and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you highlight the lines where the warning appears?

Comment: It occurs to me that 040 is 0x20, decimal 32, a space character. Is it possible that the illegal character is being reported via its octal codepoint and there is a trailing space on some data you are providing?

Comment: Space characters are also easily introduced by putting base64 encoded data into query strings without proper escaping (+ is interpreted as a space in query strings).

Comment: The idea is i am sure there are no spacing, but i am not sure about illegal characters, @DavidConrad where i could found these illegal characters mentioned? it should be documented?

Comment: Why do you call `ex.printStackTrace()` if you have a `Logger`?

Comment: That's odd. The presence of 2e and 5f make it clear that is hexadecimal, not octal. The code points listed (which may have other, legal characters between them), spell out `.$..$.@.@$$$$$$$$@@$$$$$$$$@$$$$$$$$$$@_$$$$$$$$@$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$@$$$.@$$.$$$$$$@$$$.@.$.@@$$$$$$@$`

Comment: Change `logger.warn(e.getMessage());` to `logger.warn(e.getMessage(), e);` so you can see the stack trace.

Comment: When I run the methods `postConstruct`, `encrypt` and `decrypt`, I cannot reproduce the issue. The problem may be caused by an interaction with your particular environment. By the way, you are using `PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128` in a wrong way, so the bottom line is that `key` only encapsulates `encryptorPassword`. Salt and iteration count therefore have no effect at all. Furthermore, the code only works if `encryptorPassword` is 32 bytes long. Less important, the name `encryptorEncryptionKey` is misleading, this is the source buffer for the IV and not a key.

Comment: @Topaco could you paste an answer of how i could improve the code so it's working in a correct way? thanks

Comment: I would change for GCM from `PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128` to `PBKDF2`, [here](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples/blob/master/Java/SCEE.java) you find a possible starting point.